# AS3.0: Acces child's properties of created instance

Tags: actionscript-3, instances

on my timeline i create a new instance of the class `FirstClass` with the following code:
`var firstObject:FirstClass = new FirstClass();`

the class looks like this:

```
package  {
    public class FirstClass extends MovieClip {
        public function FirstClass() {
            var tempObject:SecondClass = new SecondClass();
            tempObject.x = 100;
            tempObject.y = 200;
        }
        public function getTempObjectXpos():Number{
            return tempObject.x;            
        }
    }    
}
```

On my timeline i would like to acces the x position of the object `tempObject` can anyone help me ?

Comment: var tempX:Number = firstObject.getTempObjectXpos(); Or am I missing the issue here?

Comment: Oops. I was actually missing the point. @Dmitry is right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must declare tempObject as a member of FirstClass.
You cannot use objects (object references if be exact) between different methods of a class if they aren't members of this class.

Corrected code:

```
package  {
    public class FirstClass extends MovieClip {
        public function FirstClass() {
            tempObject = new SecondClass();
            tempObject.x = 100;
            tempObject.y = 200;
        }
        public function getTempObjectXpos():Number{
            return tempObject.x;            
        }

        private var tempObject:SecondClass = null;
    }
}
```